# TelosB GPIO interrupts in Contiki

Tags: interrupt, gpio, contiki, sleep-mode

Does anyone has a simple example where it shows how external interrupts can be handle on TelosB using Contiki. For eg, when a button is pressed then the MSP430 micro-controller  wakes up from the deep sleep mode, it does some stuffs and then switches back to deep sleep. Code snippet will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

See `platform/sky/dev/button-sensor.c` for some example code that you can adapt.

It's possible that for your use case it's enough just to use the higher-level sensor API  already provided by Contiki. There is a `button_sensor` object; see `examples/sky/test-button.c` for an example application.